# How to detect if a firebaseuser already exist on SignInWithCredentialAsync

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication, google-signin

For my unity android&ios app i am using Firebase Authentification with GoogleSignIn.
On button press (OnSignIn) the user gets a GoogleSignIn popup, on completion im signing the user with those credentials into firebase with `SignInWithCredentialAsync`.
As Result i recieve the FirebaseUser, but for my api on a backend server i need to know if the user got just created or was already existent on firebase.

Edit: Forgot to mention this exact issue happens if a user deinstall my application and reinstall it. At this point user is null and it reruns SignInWithCredentialAsync process. (i cant delete user on my database on deinstall)

```
public void OnSignIn()
{
    if (fireBaseReady == true)
    {
        if (user != null)
        {
            LoggedInAlready("login", user);
        }
        else
        {
            loginButton.SetActive(false);
            GoogleSignIn.Configuration = configuration;
            GoogleSignIn.Configuration.UseGameSignIn = false;
            GoogleSignIn.Configuration.RequestIdToken = true;
            GoogleSignIn.Configuration.RequestEmail = true;
            GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignIn().ContinueWithOnMainThread(OnAuthenticationFinished);
        }
    }
}

internal void OnAuthenticationFinished(System.Threading.Tasks.Task<GoogleSignInUser> task)
{
    if (task.IsCanceled)
    {
        warning.text = "SignIn got canceled";
        anWarning.Play("Base Layer.FontButtonFadeLong", 0, 0);
    }
    else if (task.IsFaulted)
    {
        warning.text = "SignIn was Faulted";
        anWarning.Play("Base Layer.FontButtonFadeLong", 0, 0);
    }
    else
    { 
        userToken = task.Result.IdToken;
        Credential credential = Firebase.Auth.GoogleAuthProvider.GetCredential(userToken, null);
        auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWithOnMainThread(authTask =>
        {
            if (authTask.IsCanceled)
            {
                warning.text = "Authentification is canceled";
                anWarning.Play("Base Layer.FontButtonFadeLong", 0, 0);
            }
            else if (authTask.IsFaulted)
            {
                warning.text = "Authentification is faulted";
                anWarning.Play("Base Layer.FontButtonFadeLong", 0, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                user = authTask.Result;
                LoggedInAlready("register", user);  // LOGIN OR REGISTER
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please specify app environment. Android, iOS or what?

Comment: Android and ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to check if the user was newly created is to compare their `CreationTimestamp` and `LastSignInTimestamp` in the user's [metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/auth/user-metadata#class_firebase_1_1_auth_1_1_user_metadata). If they are the same (or very close to each other), the user was just created.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect solution, thanks.
Do you have any recommandation for LastSignInTimestamp - CreationTimestamp > ?     5-10 ?

Comment: Not really. They're actually supposed to be exactly the same upon creation, but then at some point there was an offset of a few milliseconds. So it can be really low (100ms), but anything smaller than what you consider a reasonable "signing in for a second time" would be fine though.